# IBM-CLOUD putting object with private ACL got a FULL_CONTROLL permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

My main goal is to put an object in private mode

I'm using `aws-sdk-php` API to handle this case :

```php
        $client->putObject(
            [
                'ACL'    => 'private',
                'Body'   => '...',
                'Bucket' => '...',
                'Key'    => '...'
            ]
        );
```

When executing, I get the error :

```xml
"Grants" => [
  0 => array:2 [
    "Grantee" => [
      "DisplayName" => "..."
      "ID" => "..."
      "Type" => "CanonicalUser"
    ]
    "Permission" => "FULL_CONTROL"
  ]
]
```

and I still can access it via a browser!

Any idea's help to resolve it would be thankful.

Comment: Add more details. Which API or CLI?

Comment: @data_henrik I'm using Api `aws sdk php`

Comment: @data_henrik Question post was updated, would u mind sharing ur suggestions on the way to handle this case please

Comment: Based on the question I don't understand what you do, which steps, how some code or tool is called, what the permissions on S3 / COS are, or what errors or warnings you see. What is in the activity tracker? What diagnostic logs do you have? Add all these details